# Using "id" in addition to "_id" in a Document Model

Tags: mongodb, nosql, data-modeling

I've created a document model where I'm using a field named `id` in addition to MongoDB's auto-generated `_id` field.

Will this cause any problems for me down the line?

I can imagine a circumstance where something in Mongo might assume my "id" property is referring to "_id" instead, when it isn't (like some API feature with the good intention of preventing you from having to type that underscore, where in my case such a well-meaning feature would be a disaster).

Will this be ok?

Comment: For MongoDB itself this would not be an issue. You should be aware however that various ODM implementations ( mongoose for instance as just one ) actually consider `id` to be a valid "alias" for `_id`. So using other third party libraries ( or possibly switching to one later in project development ) *"could"* lead to issues. Really if the data is intended as a "unique primary key" then it should instead be stored in the `_id` field, since that is the purpose of that field.

Comment: @NeilLunn It is my understanding the _id field is not very flexible when it come to modification. I have a situation where I want the id to be based off a name field and updated uniquely when "name" changes. If I keep this field, you've given good reasons for giving it a different name.